# FPDF Add text with background color to an x/y co-ordinate

Tags: php, pdf-generation, fpdf

Question explains it all really, I need to add some text to a PDF at positions X / Y with a background color.

I know I can do this using a cell, but it seems that you cannot place a cell using an X and Y co-ord.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What if you modify your current X Y position and then place the cell?

Something like:

```
SetXY(50, 150)
Cell(100, 50, "This is my text in a box.", 1, 0, 'c', true)
```

Comment: yes this idea works :) i don't understand why did you get down voted :))

Answer (score 2):

For some reason I found it works only in this sequence: first set Y then X. for the $pdf->Cell() text box.

```
  $pdf->SetY(30);
  $pdf->SetX(70);
  $pdf->Cell(100, 10, "This is my text in a box.", 1, 0, 'e', true);
```

Comment: please describe your answer well! and Do read FAQ before answering.